# Asp.net core how to join models on razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

Good afternoon,

I have a project that i scaffolded from an existing database and it created tehe modeles and i don't understand how to join this models in one page.

models:

```cs
public partial class TblCo
{
    public int IdCo { get; set; }

    public string Compañia { get; set; } = null!;

    public int IdLocalPuesto { get; set; }

    public virtual TblLocalPuesto IdLocalPuestoNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<TblEmp> TblEmps { get; set; } = new List<TblEmp>();
}
```

```cs
public partial class TblLocalPuesto
{
    public int IdLocalPuestos { get; set; }

    public int IdLocal { get; set; }

    public int IdPuesto { get; set; }

    public virtual TblLocal IdLocalNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual TblPuesto IdPuestoNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<TblCo> TblCos { get; set; } = new List<TblCo>();

    public virtual ICollection<TblInventario> TblInventarios { get; set; } = new List<TblInventario>();

    public virtual ICollection<TblVenta> TblVentaIdLocalPuestoONavigations { get; set; } = new List<TblVenta>();

    public virtual ICollection<TblVenta> TblVentaIdLocalPuestoVNavigations { get; set; } = new List<TblVenta>();
}
```

```cs
public partial class TblLocal
{
    public int IdLocal { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? Pass { get; set; }

    public bool? Activo { get; set; }

    public int? Nivel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TblLocalPuesto> TblLocalPuestos { get; set; } = new List<TblLocalPuesto>();
}
```

right now what i'm doing is this so that i can join the 3 tables on the razor page:

```cs
IQueryable<TblCo> compañia = (from c in _context.TblCos
                                join lp in _context.TblLocalPuestos on c.IdLocalPuesto equals lp.IdLocalPuestos
                                join l in _context.TblLocals on lp.IdLocal equals l.IdLocal
                                select new TblCo()
                                {
                                    IdCo = c.IdCo,
                                    Nombre = l.Nombre,
                                    Compañia = c.Compañia
                                });
```

since the models have virtual links to the other models i think there must be a better way of doing it.

can anyone help?
Thanks!

EDIT:
this is my full page code.
the field NOMBRE comes from TblLocal and is not in TblCo,
how can i show it without adding the field to the model TblCo.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly usalentesWebApp.Models.UsalentesContext _context;

    public IndexModel(usalentesWebApp.Models.UsalentesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<TblCo> Compañia { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string searchString)
    {
        if (_context.TblCos != null)
        {
            IQueryable<TblCo> compañia =
                                        from c in _context.TblCos
                                        select new TblCo()
                                        {
                                            IdCo = c.IdCo,
                                            Nombre = c.IdLocalPuestoNavigation.IdLocalNavigation.Nombre,
                                            Compañia = c.Compañia
                                        };

            Compañia = await compañia.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all needed navigation properties to do not do joins by yourself:

```cs
var compañia = 
    from c in _context.TblCos
    select new TblCo()
    {
        IdCo = c.IdCo,
        Nombre = c.IdLocalPuestoNavigation.IdLocalNavigation.Nombre,
        Compañia = c.Compañia
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Svyatoslav. one more question. the field NOMBRE is not in tblCo model, it comes from TblLocal, i added it so that it would let me query it. but if i remove it (since it's not part of the model) how can i show it?

Comment: Create new DTO class for this particular case. Or use anonymous type.